# Better way to align bottom right

Tags: html, css

Is there a better way to align something in the bottom right of a cell?

I have a div which only contains a background image, 10px by 10px. I am using the following styles to put it in the bottom right corner. (The cell I have it in is 40px high.)

Doing it this way causes me to lose the 30px above the div. (I'm also using it as something to click, so I can click anywhere on the right instead of only the bottom corner of the cell.)

```
.time_note { float:right; width:20%; min-height:40px; display:block; 
    margin-right:-5px; }
.time_note { background:url('/images/sheet/note_marker.png') no-repeat; 
    background-position:bottom; }
```

If this could also be done NOT using margins, that would be great.

Example Image:

[image]

Comment: Check bellow solution [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810578/better-way-to-align-bottom-right)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should make your wrapping class `position:relative;` and then whatever you have inside you can position absolutely `position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;`

For example

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
}

.arrow
{
width:10px;
height:10px;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: To expand this concept just a hair, when you declare `position` absolute or relative on an element or class, that element is given its position *in relation to the position of the closest parent with some sort of positioning (other than static)*. Giving position relative and not declaring top/left gives it a position of 0px from where it would normally appear (aka no change), but allows items inside it to be properly positioned.

Comment: Create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for us so we can see what do you mean it's not showing up

Comment: Yep I see it. Ask another question about this issue, It's probably table related.

Answer (score 2):

You could `position: absolute`, and `bottom: 0; right:0;` to place it on the bottom right of the parent element (which needs `position: relative;`).  Of course, this has the danger of overlapping some other info in that element.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
background-position:bottom right;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is this, you just need to modify it to be on the right

[Sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: The link is broken