# How to align div to bottom right without using absolute position?

Tags: css, flexbox

There's many posts on how to align to bottom right, but they all used absolute, and I can't do that because I don't want my 2 elements to overlap if one happens to be too big for the window size.

I tried with float, and it works to align right, but not to align bottom

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom:10px;">

    <h1 style="display:inline;">
      This is my big title - Bla bla bla   
    </h1>

    <div style="
            font-size: small;
            float: right;
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
            font-style: italic;
            display: inline;">
        Published on Friday 11th August 2017 at 12:46   
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

You can check the result in https://jsfiddle.net/j66q82gy/7/

When the window is narrow, it doesn't matter that it's not aligned bottom, but when the window is wide and both h1 and the middle div are on the same line, it becomes apparent that it's not aligned bottom, and I need it to be aligned bottom.

I also need to keep them on the same line, so the inline should stay on both h1 and the middle div.

Edit: Flex puts thing in a sort of awkward half inline, half block like this: i.imgur dot com/YA6TdBt.png

I need something that looks like this i.imgur dot com/Awj9Bht.png (top image is my code, bottom image is photoshoped to look like what I need.)

Comment: Flex might be the way to go. Check: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please find the link bellow [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810578/better-way-to-align-bottom-right)

Comment: @charkoul OP is asking for a _non absolute positioning_ solution, which your link's answers use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Flexbox you can align both at the bottom and keep the inner `div` right aligned.

Add `display: flex; align-items: flex-end` to the outer `div`, reset the margin on the `h1` (or you can add one to the other inner `div`) and then set `margin-left: auto;` to the inner `div`

The `align-items: flex-end` will keep the inner `div` bottom aligned with the `h1` and the `margin-left: auto;` will push the inner `div` to the right.

*Note, because of the different font size, their inner metrics will create a somewhat bigger white space below the `h1`. Here I simply added a 4px bottom padding on the inner `div`, but you can also play with the overall `line-height`*

---

Updated based on a comment

If to keep the text unwrapped until they hit their parents width, add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to outer `div`

```html
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom:10px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: flex-end;">

    <h1 style="margin: 0;">
      This is my title
    </h1>
    
    <div style="
            margin-left: auto;
            font-size: small;
            padding: 0 0 4px 20px;
            font-style: italic;">
     Published on Friday 11th August 2017 at 12:46  
    </div>
  
</div>

<br>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom:10px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: flex-end;">

    <h1 style="margin: 0;">
      This is my big title - Bla bla bla   
    </h1>
    
    <div style="
            margin-left: auto;
            font-size: small;
            padding: 0 0 4px 20px;
            font-style: italic;">
     Published on Friday 11th August 2017 at 12:46  
    </div>
  
</div>

<br>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom:10px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: flex-end;">

    <h1 style="margin: 0;">
      This is my big title - Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    </h1>
    
    <div style="
            margin-left: auto;
            font-size: small;
            padding: 0 0 4px 20px;
            font-style: italic;">
     Published on Friday 11th August 2017 at 12:46  
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties instead of `float`...

**Completely updated answer**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/vp3o90e5/2/)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex div {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom:10px;" class="flex">
  <h1>
    This is my big title - Bla bla bla
  </h1>
  <div style="
            font-size: small;
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
            font-style: italic;">
    Published on Friday 11th August 2017 at 12:46

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution has both aligned centered, I need one aligned top, one aligned bottom.

Comment: flex end does not work, it does not give an inline result, it gives an half inline, half block awkward result like this http://i.imgur.com/YA6TdBt.png

Comment: and the result I need is this http://i.imgur.com/Awj9Bht.png (bottom is photoshopped)

Comment: @user8488187 ok, I think I understand now. You can add the `flex-direction` property to the container. This will allow the overlap that (I think) you want. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @user8488187 Apologies, I think I misread your question about 1000 times... I've updated my answer, hopefully for the last time :)

Comment: I would suggest using `flex-direction: row` with `margin-left: auto` on the div. Full code: `.flex { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap; } 
.flex div { align-self: flex-end; margin-left: auto; }`

Comment: @Pharaoh I think the default `flex-direction` is row... so no need to declare it here

Comment: @ovokuro The answer did specify `column` explicitly when I wrote that comment. But you are right, it could be removed.

Comment: @Pharaoh ok no problem. I updated it before seeing your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you envisioned?

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom:10px; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

    <h1 style="display:inline;">
      This is my big title - Bla bla bla   
    </h1>

    <div style="
            font-size: small;
            float: right;
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
            font-style: italic;
            align-self: flex-end;
            margin-left: auto;">
        Published on Friday 11th August 2017 at 12:46   
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eq6jLnct/5/

Change the height to whatever you need. Or just use min-height.

Please not that flexbox is not supported for all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-box

Comment: No. There should be no height settings. This is a title and meta description, not an entire page. When you remove the height and use a narrow window, your solution gives this result which does not look good. http://i.imgur.com/YA6TdBt.png The solution should look the same as my original code in a narrow window, but different in a wide window. And using media does not work, because titles are dynamic, some are very long, you can't predict with media the size it will be.

Comment: So remove height completely. I wanted to demonstrate the bottom position.

Comment: I wasn't finished writing, I just clicked enter to do a line break and it posted my comment. Please see my update on my previous comment.

Comment: I see the question is answerred. I updated the code a bit. "flex-wrap> wrap" is needed to avoid wrong wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this codePen](https://codepen.io/shabudeen/pen/dzavVW) I added, here's the CSS:

```
float: right;
transform: translateY(0px);
```

Comment: Your solution is not inline, it's on 2 lines. I need on 1 line.

Comment: Ok you can remove display: inline-block; then add width: 100%;

Comment: that is still not inline. This is your result http://i.imgur.com/1zVsbM5r.png 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```html
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; padding-bottom:10px;display: table;">

    <h1 style="display:inline;">
      This is my big title - Bla bla bla   
    </h1>
    
    <div style="
            font-size: small;
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
            font-style: italic;
           display: table-cell;
           vertical-align:bottom;">
     Published on Friday 11th August 2017 at 12:46  
    </div>
  
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

Methord 2:

You can go through the link of [flexbox](http://cssreference.io/flexbox/) as it is very easy to use and highly resoposive.